# Flutter - best approach to create TabledToggledButtons?

Tags: flutter, widget, togglebutton

I would like my toggle buttons to be layout in a table, and not as a single row.
The number of toggle buttons is not static - 
that is upon init I load a resource which contains a list of all the texts that should become the toggle buttons.

Looked at a number of approaches, each has its issues:

1. Create a list of ToggleButtons and a list of lists of bools to store the appropriate selected state as a data structure to divide the toggle buttons into a number of rows. The problem with this approach is in the implementation of the onPressed method - how to get a reference to the appropriate element in the list of lists of bools? Or in other words - how to get a reference to ToggleButtons object from within the onPressed method?
2. Use key property to pass the index of the current ToggleButtons. It is not intended for this purpose, so it is a bad practice, also again, there seems to be no straightforward way to access the key property from the onPressed method.
3. Extend the ToggleButtons class, and specifically override its build method. This is considered an anti-pattern in Flutter in general. Specifically In this approach, as we want all the functionality to remain the same, and change only the internal Row -> Table widget generation in the build method, it looks like we would have to duplicate all the code of this method, which is a bad idea as it might brake things as it changes in future versions of this widget
4. Create a table of checkbox / switch widgets as an alternative, which should work easily, but I want the look & feel of toggle buttons, not checkboxes or switches :)

I must be missing something simple!

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I have a new idea :)
A table of FlatButtons! Will be probably possible to achieve similar UI to ToggleButtons. Will try it in a bit.
I would still love to hear other suggestions regarding ToggleButtons.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SwitchListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile-class.html).

The entire list tile is interactive: tapping anywhere in the tile toggles the switch. Tapping and dragging the Switch also triggers the onChanged callback.

To ensure that onChanged correctly triggers, the state passed into value must be properly managed. This is typically done by invoking State.setState in onChanged to toggle the state value.

The value, onChanged, activeColor, activeThumbImage, and inactiveThumbImage properties of this widget are identical to the similarly-named properties on the Switch widget.

The title, subtitle, isThreeLine, and dense properties are like those of the same name on ListTile.

The selected property on this widget is similar to the ListTile.selected property, but the color used is that described by activeColor, if any, defaulting to the accent color of the current Theme. No effort is made to coordinate the selected state and the value state; to have the list tile appear selected when the switch is on, pass the same value to both.

The switch is shown on the right by default in left-to-right languages (i.e. in the ListTile.trailing slot) which can be changed using controlAffinity. The secondary widget is placed in the ListTile.leading slot.

To show the SwitchListTile as disabled, pass null as the onChanged callback.